# Link only needed symbols when compiling an executable with a Shared Library

Tags: c++, c, linker, shared-libraries

I'm working on a heavy project that has a lot of static libraries that are interdependent. Furthermore some symbols are redundant between some libraries, with different implementations. My goal is to make the project work with shared libraries.

I tried to compile an executable with one of my shared libs, and **I get undefined symbols errors on functions that my executable isn't using**. After some research I understood that the dynamic linker works in very different ways than the static linker. If I understood right, when linking a shared library, all symbols need to be resolved as the whole library is loaded in the memory.

A simple workaround would be to add all the dependencies of my libraries when compiling the executable. But they're so full of dependencies that this sometimes means adding 10+ libraries to the command line, and this would be for something like a hundred executable.

So far I tried using `-Wl,--as-needed`, `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs`, and opening the shared object with `dlopen` to get the function I want with `dlsym`. But all of these methods fail at one point or another.

My question is: **Are you forced to resolve every undefined symbol of a dynamic library when linking it against an executable ?**

Comment: You can't use `dlopen` to open a DLL.  `dlopen` is Posix and DLLs are Windows (and while DLLs are Shared Objects are similar, you are working in one of the areas where they are different).  Which platform(s) are you using?

Comment: It was a typo, it's not a DLL it's a shared library (.so). I'm compiling on a linux server.

Comment: "Furthermore some symbols are redundant between some libraries, with different implementations" - That looks like asking for trouble. And maintenance nightmare. And how do you think unresolved symbols which are apparently required should be handled otherwise? It seems this is not well thought.

Comment: I won't say it's good design, but it allows you to chose different implementations of a functions by linking a different lib than the standard one.

Comment: @Olaf I didn't find a definitive answer about how unresolved symbols should be handled anywhere. That's why I posted here, hoping to get an answer from someone with knowledge in the matter.

Comment: @JeremyCaradec: I'm asking **you** what you think **your** program should do if a function is called which does not exist. It's asking for reason, not implementation.

Comment: @Olaf The linker can see the symbols it needs in the executable code. I want the linker to get only these symbols and not the rest. '-Wl,--as-needed' does that but it doesn't get past direct dependencies, even when used like this :
'gcc -Wl,--as-needed main.c -L. -lmul -ladd'
libadd and libmul are libraries created for testing purposes, libmul has a function mul2 that use the function add in libadd.
It gives me an undefined reference to add.
What I want is for the dynamic linker to behave the same way as the static linker. Only care for used symbols, don't try to resolve symbols that aren

Comment: That aren't used*

Comment: There are two stages of linking for shared libraries.

Comment: I just saw that my title is very wrong and misleading, it's not about exporting symbols. It's about linking only the symbols needed to an executable.
Now when you say that there are two steps in the linking process I don't know what you're referring to. The only resource I found and read is [Ulrich Drepper's paper](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).

Comment: Well actually I tried to read a lot more about ELF format and so on. But I didn't find what I was looking for. It just seems weird to me that if the linker can make out the symbols it needs, it will still want to resolve symbols that aren't used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Details of dynamic linking and the kinds of objects involved vary across environments and toolchains.  On Linux, where you say you are, and on Solaris, and several other UNIX-y platforms, you are looking at ELF objects and semantics.

> So far I tried using `-Wl,--as-needed`,
>   `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs`,

These both have their full effect at (static) link time.  The first tells the linker that the libraries following it on the command line should be linked in only if they resolve at least one as-yet undefined symbol.  The latter tells the linker to not worry about resolving symbols in shared libraries included in the link.  That has nothing to do with the behavior of the *dynamic* linker when you run the program.

> and opening the shared object with `dlopen` to get the function I want with `dlsym`.

`dlopen` instructs the dynamic linker to link in a shared object at runtime that was not specified in the binary as a required shared library.  Its behavior at that point can be modulated by the flags passed to `dlopen`, but the options available are not more than can be specified at link time.  There is little reason to use `dlopen` when you actually know at link time what libraries you need.

> **Are you forced to resolve every undefined symbol of a dynamic library
>   when linking it against an executable ?**

Focusing on ELF and the GNU toolchain, no.  `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs` serves precisely the purpose of avoiding that.  But as you've discovered, that comes with caveats.

In the first place, in every shared object, every symbol referring to *data* needs to be resolved at runtime by the dynamic linker, no matter how you linked the various shared objects, including the main program.  This is primarily an operational consideration -- the dynamic linker has no way to defer resolving symbols referring to objects because it has no good way to trap attempts to access them.

On the other hand, it *is* possible to defer resolution of symbols referring to functions until their first use.  In fact, this is the GNU linker's default, but you can reaffirm this by passing `-Wl,-z,lazy` to `gcc` when linking.  Note well, however, that this sets a property *of the object being linked*, so you should ensure that every shared object is built with that link option (but ordinarily they are because, again, that's the default).

Additionally, you should be aware that the dynamic linker's behavior can be influenced by environment variables.  In particular, lazy binding will be disabled if the dynamic linker finds `LD_BIND_NOW` set to a nonempty string in the runtime environment.

> A simple workaround would be to add all the dependencies of my
>   libraries when compiling the executable. But they're so full of
>   dependencies that this sometimes means adding 10+ libraries to the
>   command line, and this would be for something like a hundred
>   executable.

And what's the big deal with that, really?  Surely you have a well-factored Makefile (or several) to help you, so it shouldn't be a big deal to ensure that all the libraries are linked.  Right?

But you should also consider refactoring your libraries, especially if "interdependent" means there are loops in the dependency graph.  Dynamic linking is different from static linking, as you've discovered, and the differences are sometimes more subtle than those you're presently struggling with.  Although it is not a hard rule, I urge you to avoid creating situations where the shared objects used by one process contain among them multiple definitions of the same external symbol, especially if that symbol is actually used.

---

**Update**

The above discussion focuses on linking shared libraries to an executable, but there is another important consideration: how the libraries themselves are linked.  Each ELF object, whether executable or shared library, carries its own list of needed shared libraries.  The dynamic linker will recursively include all of these in the list of shared libraries to be loaded (immediately) at program startup, notwithstanding its behavior with respect to lazy binding of symbols referring to functions.

Therefore, if you want an executable not to require a given shared library X, then not only that executable itself but also every shared library it does rely upon must avoid expressing a dependency on X.  If some of the shared libs require X when used in conjunction with other programs, then that puts the onus on *you* to link in all the needed libraries when building those programs (otherwise, you can arrange to link only direct dependencies).  You can tell the GNU linker to build shared libraries this way by passing it the `--allow-shlib-undefined` flag.

Here is a complete proof of concept:

***main.c***

```
int mul(int, int);

int main(void) {
    return mul(2, 3);
}
```

***mul.c***

```
int add(int, int);

int mul(int x, int y) {
    return x * y;
}

int mul2(int x, int y) {
    return add(x, y) * add(x, -y);
}
```

***Makefile***

```
CC = gcc
LD = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -fPIC -DPIC
LDFLAGS = -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs
SHLIB_LDFLAGS = -shared -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined

all: main

main: main.o libmul.so
    $(LD) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

libmul.so: mul.o
    $(LD) $(CFLAGS) $(SHLIB_LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f main main.o libmul.so mul.o
```

**Demo**

> ```
> $ make
> gcc -g -O2 -fPIC -DPIC   -c -o main.o main.c
> gcc -g -O2 -fPIC -DPIC   -c -o mul.o mul.c
> gcc -g -O2 -fPIC -DPIC -shared -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -o libmul.so mul.o
> gcc -g -O2 -fPIC -DPIC -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs -o main main.o libmul.so
> $ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd) ./main
> $ echo $?
> 6
> $
> ```

Note that the `-zlazy` linker option discussed in comments is omitted, as it's the default.

Comment: Thanks for this dedicated answer. If I understood right when I compile `gcc main.c -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs -Wl,-rpath,. -L. -lmul -ladd` It shouldn't give me `./main: symbol lookup error: ./libmul.so: undefined symbol: add` ? I compiled both libraries with `-Wl,-z,lazy` and I made sure LD_BIND_NOW was an empty string too.

Comment: Also it's not that my Makefile isn't factorized, it's that every executable have different dependencies. Sure, I could just link every lib to every executable, but that seems overkill and might give bad performance.

Comment: Neverming my last comment, I just realized that using `-Wl,--as-needed` and passing every libs can be a solution too. I'll try and implement that for a start, I'll see if it affects the performance or not to load many libs.

Comment: @JeremyCaradec, I cannot unconditionally agree with your assertion, but I just contructed a proof of concept example here that is indeed linked as you show, and in which `libmul` indeed depends on `libadd`.  It runs without error and produces the expected output.

Comment: Also, better to ensure that `LD_BIND_NOW` is not defined in the environment at all than to define it to an empty string.

Comment: I'm going to try to find out what's wrong with my code then. Maybe try it on another machine.

Comment: Looks like ld didn't like a relative path on rpath. I managed to successfully compile libadd with libmul and execute it with expected results. But now if I add a function that has an unresolved dependency in libadd AND not call the function in main, it compiles but doesn't execute. It still tries to resolve the symbol even though everything is compiled with -Wl,-z,lazy and LD_BIND_NOW doesn't have a value. I even tried setting LD_BIND_LAZY to 1 but the results are still the same. It tries to resolve undefined symbols that aren't used.

Comment: @JeremyCaradec, I do not observe that behavior here.  Check exactly what error message you get: is it in fact complaining about an unresolved *symbol*?  Depending on how I build things, I can get an unwanted direct dependency on an additional *shared library*, and the dynamic linker may then complain if that library is not available at run time.

Comment: This is what I have `gcc main.c -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs -L. -lmul -Wl,-rpath,. -o main` that gives the follow `symbol lookup error: libmul.so: undefined symbol: add`. My main calls the function `mul(a, b)` which just multiplies a and b then returns the value. But there's also `mul2(a, b)` in libmul which utilize the function `add(a, b)` in libadd. My main does NOT call mul2.

Comment: Additional information: the libraries are still compiled with `-Wl,-z,lazy`. I also tried to add it when compiling main.c but it still gives the same results. If you really can execute your shared libraries without resolving all their symbols I'd like you to share your proof of concept.

Comment: @JeremyCaradec, there you go, one POC.  Also, additional commentary that probably helps get to the central issue, which I think is not so much how you link your libraries to the executable, but how you build them in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a LOT man, you really helped me there. Seems like my problem was that I was not compiling mul.o with `-fpic` tho I think `-fpie` makes the code more optimized cause it tells the compiler that it will be used for a shared library.

Comment: @JeremyCaradec, I'm glad to have helped.  Regarding `-fpie`, however, you seem to have a misunderstanding.  Objects compiled with `-fpie` can only be linked (directly) into executables.  That's what the 'e' stands for.  `-fpic` or `-fPIC` is *precisely* what you need to use for objects that are going into shared libraries.